# Gridview updatecommand not working with 2 worded database columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, updatecommand

Here is a working version of the gridview updatecommand

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="MatchDataSource" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SYR1]"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [dbo].[SYR1] SET Fname = @Fname
        WHERE ID=@ID 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="Fname" />
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="Lname" />
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="ID" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True"></asp:CommandField>
    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="First Name"  DataField="fname" SortExpression="fname"><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="false" HeaderText="Last Name" DataField="lname"    SortExpression="lname"><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle> </asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
```

The problem I have is I have database columns with 2 names, i.e. instead of "fname" I have "First Name". The datafield is fine and will take a 2 word column name

```
<asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="First Name"  DataField="First Name" SortExpression="fname"><ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right"></ItemStyle></asp:BoundField>
```

The problem is I cant save a 2 worded parameter so I'm not sure how I get the update to work... Below is an unsuccesful attempt. Can anyone help me out with it please.

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [dbo].[SYR1] SET [First Name] = @First name
        WHERE ID=@ID 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="First Name" />
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="Last Name" />
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="ID" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

Comment: Did you tried `[First Name]` ??

Comment: It's assigning the parameter is the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

Refer link for rules
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223962.aspx

**Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.**

Change your parameter names:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [dbo].[SYR1] SET [First Name] = @FirstName
        WHERE ID=@ID 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="FirstName" />
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="LastName" />
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="ID" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

Comment: ^THIS. By default SqlDataSource creates the 'SELECT * FROM' as SelectCommand, which does work fine to display but doesn't allow to update the table.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution one**

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [dbo].[SYR1] SET [First Name] = @First name
        WHERE ID=@ID 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>">
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="[First Name]" />
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="[Last Name]" />
            <asp:Parameter Type="String" Name="ID" />
        </UpdateParameters>
```

If it doesn't work, then you can use aliasing,

**Solution two**

```
Select [First Name] as Fname, ...
from tableName
```